# How can I merge 2 search forms together?

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I am doing [my website](https://localchain.co.uk/shop/) on Wordpress.
I have 2 search forms that appear separate on my website and I was wondering how could I merge them into one.

The first search form searches for products [First search form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF81Y.jpg)
The second one searches for the location of the products [Second search form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5XdH.jpg)

Sorry for asking this silly question and thank you for your help :D

Comment: By "merge them into one" do you mean that you want to perform a search using the values input into both of them?  Like what they are searching for, and also within a distance of their location?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). and this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to see what we need. When you are ready, you can update your question with details of what you have tried and your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help.

Comment: Hello Adam Winter. Yes that's what I mean. Basicly a search form that does the products and location together.

Comment: I have tried to do code on html on the google chrome inspect but I don't know php and that's the language if I am not wrong that is beeing used in there. Thank you to try to help I will update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is what you need to start learning.  It is the essential other half of webpage design.  With Javascript you can get the value from anything on the page.  Here's the basic code for pulling the values from the inputs of two different forms and posting them to your PHP file.

```
<!--first form-->
<form>
    <input type="text" id="product" name="product">
</form>

<!--second form-->
<form>
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city">
</form>

<button onclick="continuePost()">Submit Both</button>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
function continuePost() {

    var product = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("product").value);
    var city = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("city").value);
    var params = "product="+product+"&city="+city;

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        
        var myResponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);  //send a JSON response back from your PHP file
        
        if(myResponse.hasOwnProperty('error')){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = myResponse.error;
        }else{
            var result1 = myResponse.myResult1;
            var result2 = myResponse.myResult2[0];   //or whatever key and value pairs that you used in the JSON response that you sent back from you PHP file
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result1;
        }

    }else{
      window.setTimeout(failed(), 3000);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "yourPHPfile.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send(params);
}

function failed(){
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Failed to connect to server.';
}
</script>
```

yourPHPfile.php

```
<?php

$obj = new stdClass();
     $obj->dateread = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");

if(!isset($_POST["product"])){
    $obj->error = 'No product.';
    echo json_encode($obj);
    exit;
}else {
    $product=$_POST["product"];
    }

if(!isset($_POST["city"])){
    $obj->error = 'No city.';
    echo json_encode($obj);
    exit;
}else {
    $city=$_POST["city"];
    }

$obj->myResult1 = 'Info you want back from your PHP file.';
$obj->myResult2 = ['array', 'of', 'info', 'you', 'want'];

echo json_encode($obj);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this gives me some guidance! Amazing comment! Thank you thank you thank you!!!!!! <3

Comment: I've added a bare-bones example of the PHP file that will work with the page. You're welcome.

Comment: Thanks too you I could find where my code is coming from! I was surprised that my php code was inside the js file instead of php! Thank you for your help. I will try to do it in the next few days.